# Get php boolean value with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, boolean

I want to get php booelan value with javascript.
That is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

var isValue = $j(<?php isset($getResult[]); ?>);

alert(isValue);

</script>
```

Comment: `echo` it? `echo variable ? "true" : "false"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    var isValue = $j(<?php if (isset($getResult)){ echo true;} else {echo false;} ?>);

    alert(isValue);

</script>
```

You cannot use  `$getResult[]` for reading using issest. It will return fatal error or you have to specify some index in the array.

If you want to check if it is an array then you can use :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

    var isValue = $j(<?php if (isset($getResult) && is_array($getResult)){ echo true;} else {echo false;} ?>);

    alert(isValue);

</script>
```

Comment: this example is not working. you need to php echo in quotes. for example:

`<script>
    var isValue = <?php echo isset($getResult) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>
</script>`

Answer (score 3):

php is a server side programming, and javascript is client side. so you need to "echo" the php value to get result on javascript

```
var isValue = $j(<?php echo isset($getResult[]) ? "true" : "false"; ?>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to convert the boolean result of isset() into a string representation of 'true' or 'false' so that it can be understood by the javascript parser. Like this:

```
var isValue = $j(<?php isset($getResult[]) ? echo 'true' : echo 'false'; ?>);
```

Comment: hehe :) So the opener can be twice sure that this is the correct answer.